# Why is the value of a cookie I'm setting (a string) increasing by one when being set from a $_GET?

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, wamp

When I set a cookie to a two number string using a variable set by $_GET, it gets stored as one number higher in the cookie. But, the variable is actually correct! It happens in Chrome, but not Firefox. I'm on a WAMP server and accessing locally.

If I set test.php?a=07

```
$val = $_GET['a'];
setcookie('t', $val, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
var_dump($val);
```

returns

```
string '07' (length=2)
```

Here's where things get crazy. In another script:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE['t']);
```

returns

```
string '08' (length=2)
```

Like 90% of the time. If I set the cookie a bunch, sometimes it will return '07'. I've checked the cookie itself and it's getting stored as the higher number. So it's not the retrieving. It also works with other numbers.

If I set the variable in the script it doesn't happen.

```
$val = '07';
setcookie('t', $val, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
var_dump($val);
```

Works fine. As does:

```
setcookie('t', '07', time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
var_dump($val);
```

What could it be?

EDIT:
The code above is the complete files. The only thing missing is an opening

1. WAMP server is running.
2. Visit localsite/test.php?a=07 in Chrome
3. View and record variable dump (in this case '07').
4. Visit localsite/test2.php in Chrome. That consists of: `<?php var_dump($_COOKIE['t']);`
5. View and record variable dump (in this case '08').
6. Look at cookie via Chrome settings to see that it's not a retrieving or displaying error. Cookie t='08'.

WAMP Server 2.4
Apache 2.4.4
PHP 5.4.12

Comment: Not likely. Something else in your code is changing it.

Comment: No, this is it. I copied the code to a new test file and kept removing and simplifying to get to the core of the problem. What I put in above isn't a hypothetical example, it's literally the code I'm running and the results I'm getting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you show the complete code from both the pages you are using to test with. Also version numbers of WAMP and Apache and PHP. And the steps you use when testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I should have really paid more attention to:

> It happens in Chrome, but not Firefox.

It was being caused by a Chrome extension. I forgot I had an extension left over from a previous project. It was one of those "next page" extensions. For example, you could click next to go from website.com/img1.jpg to website.com/img2.jpg and so on. It must have been pre-loading the next page in sequence. This changed the GET variable and caused the cookie to be changed. Removed extension, problem gone. So much frustration from such a simple thing!